# Can't pass javascript appended html form fields to rails controller

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, append, parameters

I'm making a form using ruby-on-rails, but there's a section in the form that I'm not  understanding what's happening.

The form has a field named antecedentes, in english is translated as backgrounds.
I have a select tag with all the different backgrounds, and a button that calls a javascript function called addBackground. The addBackground function appends some html fields to a table div thats inside the form.

Everithing is fine until I press the submit button, the problem is that the added background fields are not being passed through the rails params to the create action in my application's controller.

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">      
  <h4><%= t('titles.backgrounds') %></h4>
  <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
    <%= text_field_tag 'text_bgd_bgd', 7, placeholder: t('st_sheet.st_dots'), class: "form-control" %>
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
    <%= select_tag 'select_bgd', options_for_select(@backgrounds), include_blank: false, class: "form-control" %>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="add_user" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" , onclick="addBackground(select_bgd)" ><span class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="table_backgrounds" class="table table-hover table-striped ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><%= label_tag t('Backgrounds.background') %></th>
          <th><%= label_tag t('Backgrounds.value') %></th>
          <th><%= label_tag t('Backgrounds.operation') %></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Here's my javascript code:

```
function addBackground(select) {
  var backgroud_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var background_name  = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

  if (!document.getElementById('row_' + background_name)) {
    $('#table_backgrounds > tbody:last').append(
      '<tr id="row_' + background_name + '">' +
        '<td>' + background_name + '<input type="hidden" id="bgd_id_' + backgroud_id + '" value="' + backgroud_id + '" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="number" id="bgd_' + background_name + '" value="0" min="0" max="5" class="form-control" onclick="refillManager(bgd_' + background_name + ')" /></td>' +
        '<td><button id="bgd_remove_' + backgroud_id + '" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" onclick="removeBackground(bgd_' + background_name + ', \'' + background_name + '\')"><span class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    ); 
  } else {
    alert("O antecedente "+background_name+" já foi adicionado.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I dnt see `form` for `submit` button, what did u mean there?

Comment: I didn't posted the form submit button cause I think its not that important to this problem. I just want to pass the value of the appended fields to the my application's controller through rails params.

Comment: did u try my answer ? also whats yr url for controller ?

Comment: I have tried your answer, it didn't work. The url is this, POST   /tables/:table_id/st_mages(.:format)

Comment: what u have tried so far, to POST a data ? any forms ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to pass a data, just fetch through `document.getElementById()`

**JavaScript:**

```
    function addBackground() {
        var select = document.getElementById("select_bgd");
        var backgroud_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        var background_name  = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        ...
   }
```

**html:**

```
<%= select_tag 'select_bgd', options_for_select(@backgrounds),
               include_blank: false, class: "form-control", id: "select_bgd" %>
```

and leave it empty `onClick` function

```
onclick="addBackground()"
```

Comment: This solution doesn't change the params, or add the field values to the rails params.